# Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientResult<System.IO.Stream>' to 'System.IO.Stream'

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom

I have the following code inside my server-side ER, to get a file and added inside another folder :-

```
byte[] fileBytes = softemplete.File.OpenBinary();
SPFile destFile = currentDL.RootFolder.Files.Add(destUrl, fileBytes, false);
```

and i want to change the code to CSOM, so i define the following

```
var fileBytes = softemplete.File.OpenBinaryStream();
FileCreationInformation fci = new FileCreationInformation();
fci.Overwrite = false;
fci.Url = destUrl;
fci.ContentStream = fileBytes;
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File destFile = currentDL.RootFolder.Files.Add(fci);
```

but i am getting this error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientResult<System.IO.Stream>' to 'System.IO.Stream'` on `fci.ContentStream = fileBytes;`.. any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FileCreationInformation.ContentStream property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/jj168726(v%3Doffice.15)) is basically of type System.IO.Stream, whereas, [File.OpenBinaryStream method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/jj170439(v%3Doffice.15)) returns Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientResult type.

Check [this post from Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/upload-large-files-sample-app-for-sharepoint) for different ways of uploading files to SharePoint and use the one best suited for your need.